# How to run all tests in class repeatedly based upon config method in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a test class A, in which i have 10 test methods and there is a config method setup() and my requirement is as follows :

Run config method 10 times and after each run if there is no exception in config, execute all 10 tests i.e

a) for i=1

b) run config, if success then execute all 10 tests else skip cases

c) increment i

d) if i <= 10 execute step b) else exit

How to achieve this in testng ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider testng listeners? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use factory method to instantiate 10 objects of class A. Iterate in a loop and create 10 objects. A sample method with 2 objects is given below

```
@Factory
public Object[] factoryMethod() {
    return new Object[] { new A(), new A() };
}
```

Create a setup method and annotate with @BeforeClass. This method will be called before executing all your test cases. If this setup method throws an exception then all your test methods will be skipped.

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup () {
    System.out.println("Before Class");
}
```

Hope this helps :)